# NotAuthorizedException: Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool when using Google as Identity Provider

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito

Upon calling federatedSignIn using Google it returns a

"NotAuthorizedException: Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool when using Google as Identity Provider"

I'm using a 3rd party library namely angular5-social-login for logging in social providers such as google. I believe I have configured this as expected in both cognito, and federated entities.

Here's my sample code

```
this.socialAuthService.signIn(socialPlatformProvider).then(
      (userData) => {
        console.log(socialPlatform+" sign in data : " , userData);
        // Now sign-in with userData
        let user = {
          email:userData.email,
          name: userData.name
        }
        Auth.federatedSignIn(
          // Initiate federated sign-in with Google identity provider 
          'google',
          { 
              // the JWT token
              token: userData.idToken,
              expires_at: null
          },
          // a user object
          user
      ).then(a => {
          // ...
          console.log(a)
      });
```

Here's

Here's the configuration I did

[image]

and on the federated entities

[image]

Where both ahve the same google client id

I believe I have already configured as necessary in both user pool, and federated entities. However I am still encountering the same issue

Answer (score 1):

That problem happened to me when i was using `cognito` to authentication.

I suggest you to check your credentials and make sure your cognito App Client ID is correct.

You can check that value from your user pool

```
App integration => App client settings
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the specific library you are using, but I believe there is a good chance the problem is due to the 'google' string you are using. You should be passing 'accounts.google.com' instead.

Other issue that come to mind: are you sure you need a user pool? Perhaps you only need an identity pool (federated identity)? if you just want to allow your users to sign in with Google you do not need a user pool.